# Invoke soap wcf service in Fiddler like in Wcf test client

Tags: wcf, fiddler, wcf-rest, wcftestclient

I have service which should support SOAP and REST.
web.config

```
<system.web>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet" />
    <add name="HttpPost" />
  </protocols>
</webServices>
<httpRuntime  executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="1048576" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

and contract

```
    [OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetData")]
List<FieldInfo> GetSerializedData();
```

When I invoke REST service in Fiddler Request builder I get result in JSON and XML clearly. But I can not find way to invoke soap endpoint,always get 404 error

> Not Found
>
> ### Not Found
>
> ---
>
> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

For me it is strange cause in WCF TEST Client return SOAP withou problem, so why Fiddler have problem. I invoke in Fiddler directly wcf service methods on bindings.

Comment: Creating a SOAP request is quite a bit of work - it's **NOT** just two lines of HTTP GET request..... you need to obey all the SOAP rules... bottom line: for **SOAP**, just use the **WCF Test Client** - that's what it does best! SOAP and REST are two **very different** worlds....

Comment: [Check out a sample SOAP request](http://forums.asp.net/t/928000.aspx/1) - do you **really** want to type all of this into Fiddler to send it??

Comment: @marc_s  It's not a problem to type all this in fiddler, but even when I type it in c# I can't return SOAP body message. Always get 404 or 400 error ;/