# How to host wcf Routing Service on IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, wcf-routing

So this is in relation to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899657/how-to-do-wcf-routing-service-using-xpath).

So I have an existing wcf service running already, hosted on IIS. I created a Router Service that will do some XPath filtering on the header. So if the header is match then go to service1. 
Now, I hosted my Router Service on IIS and I can access it like http://iis.com/myrouter/router.svc/ and give me this wsdl stuff. Now when I try to request a service method on service1 like this http://iis.com/myrouter/router.svc/general/getMyMethod?blah=blahblah. It gives me a 404 error. I used fiddler by the way.

On my request through fiddler I added my custom header like "service_version:1". I used a namespace by the way on my `<namespaceTable>` but I don't know how to append it on my request. Anyway, my main concern is how can I make my Router Service work on IIS?

Update: I am using `System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService` by the way. So what I am trying to accomplish is Routing Services.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes sir. And I have an existing wcf service that is working already and I want to do some routing for versioning purpose.

Comment: Did you test this same service this way prior?  The reason I'm asking this question is because if it's a SOAP service you wouldn't access it with a URL quite like that - the SOAP package has to be constructed and sent in.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you sir. My service is capable of SOAP and REST. So I've tried requesting directly for service1 like this. http://iss.com/service.svc/getSomething?id=234234

Comment: I modified my answer to address that - it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely facing this.  A SOAP service can't be accessed that way because it relies on the SOAP package.  Here is another article that should lead you down the right direction.  However, the direction it leads you down is that testing a SOAP service by hand is *not* to be desired and probably a futile effort.

However, one note is that it leads you to use the WCF Test Client - that's the best direction to go my friend and it's very easy to use. Provide the URL and it will do the rest.

[Invoke soap wcf service in Fiddler like in Wcf test client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386945/invoke-soap-wcf-service-in-fiddler-like-in-wcf-test-client)

**Accessing the RESTful Endpoint**

If you're trying to test the RESTful endpoint then the issue is likely surrounding the routing that is configured.  Please refer to this link for assistance - make sure you're setting up your service the same because the attributes they use build the routing properly.  Remember that you're not going to reference the RESTful endpoint with the same address as the SOAP endpoint.

http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx

You can also check out this link.

[Hosting WCF soap and rest endpoints side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366103/hosting-wcf-soap-and-rest-endpoints-side-by-side)

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. My Service1 is working the way it should be and I can do a request to it. What I am trying to accomplish is Routing Services. So I created a Router Service that does the routing to my existing WCF service. My problem right now is my Router Service is not working.